# Add a per-domain filter in sieve

Tags: email, postfix, dovecot, spam-filter, sieve

How can I set up a per-domain filter in sieve/dovecot?

In documentation I can see per-user setting: sieve = ~/.dovecot.sieve, and right now I'm using global filter: sieve_before = /etc/dovecot/sieve/global . However, I'd like to be able to set up filters per domain basis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short - you can't.

Dovecot allow only global and per-user sieves.

`before/default/after` sieves are global and applied to each message. If you are sure that you want to process all messages in the same way you have to set up the `sieve_before` filter, not the `default`. But there is a not well explained trap here.

`sieve_before` may consist of number of rules. First matched rule will be applied and sieve processing will be stopped. If you want then to pass message to the `user` sieve for additional filtering you have to add the verb `keep` to the end of specific rule.

```
require "fileinto";
# rule:[some_domain]
if header :contains "From" "some.domain.tld"
{
  fileinto "some_domain_tld";
  keep;
}
elseif . . . . . 
{
    . . . . .
   keep;
}
else
{
   keep;
}
```

If `keep` verb is omitted then sieve engine will treat that as implicit verb `stop` and message wouldn't be passed to the `user`'s sieve.